# Search a content of a xml string by php

Tags: php, xml

Is there a way to search for a string in an XML file using PHP?

```
<xml>
<some_tag>
  <cont>Random string</cont>
  <shortcut>RStr</shortcut>
</some_tag>
<some_tag>
  <cont>Message</cont>
  <shortcut>MSG</shortcut>
</some_tag>
</xml>
```

I'm searching for a way that I can search for "Random string" and get the shortcut tag (RStr in this case). If nothing is found, I want to output false.

Comment: **Outputs false instead of** Where is the code which outputs false?

Comment: You can use `simplexml_load_string` or `simplexml_load_file()` for parse `xml'. These function will return a ` SimpleXMLElement class object`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in combination with [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Try the example code below:

```
$xml = "<xml>
<some_tag>
  <cont>Random string</cont>
  <shortcut>RStr</shortcut>
</some_tag>
<some_tag>
  <cont>Message</cont>
  <shortcut>MSG</shortcut>
</some_tag>
</xml>";


$searchCont = "Random string";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml );

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = $xpath->query('//some_tag/cont[contains(.,"'.$searchCont.'")]/../shortcut');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    // this is your shortcut
    echo $tag->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in /home/blah/bablala/work_in_proggerss/index.php on line 21

Comment: i just addeded echo $tags; and put it onto the <?php ?>

Comment: You can not echo the `$tags` because `DOMXPath::query()` returns a DOMNodeList, if you want to echo your result, do it like in the code above. You can pass it to a variable instead of echoing if you want to use it later.